# How do i merge my node project with angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, web

I have made a project in nodeJs which updates data of my database and I've made a separate project in angular for designing front end of the form.

How do I merge these two different projects so that form data passed in angular project is handled by nodejs project?
so basically I want to make a full app having both front and well as back end.
Thanks.

Comment: call a rest-api from angular (Front end) which calls your nodeJS and your nodeJS then updates the database...

Comment: @AkberIqbal thanks. Could you be more specific? I am new in web development.

Comment: do you know about expressJS ?

Comment: @AkberIqbal yes. I used express in nodeJs.

Comment: so call the rest api from Angular - app.get('/url', ()=>{}) in your nodeJS will be invoked; google and read an article on MEAN stack which will help you get through it quickly

Comment: basically you point angular build directory to nodejs apps static directory - you'll end up with index.html and angular js files there that will get served from the express app root ('/'). Then in your express app define rest api routes, say '/api' and call these from Angular to read/update data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've developped your Rest Api in NodeJs with all the urls, you can call them in Angular by following the steps:

1- In Angular, create a service ( ng generate service dummyService)

2- Create the functions to interact with you NodeJs server:

```
dummyFunction() {

   return this.http.get(backendUrl).pipe(map(res => res))
}
```

3- Call the Service in your components and retrieve/Send Data as you wish

Comment: backendUrl means?